# Add custom menu to a Google Document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm discovering Google App Script and I'm very attracted by its potential.

I want to improve a Google Document by adding a custom menu.
I found many how-to to make this in a spreadsheet but nothing for document.

Did I miss anything ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#getActiveDocument()

```
 // Add a custom menu to the active document, including a separator and a sub-menu.
 function onOpen() {
   DocumentApp.getUi()
       .createMenu('My Menu')
       .addItem('My Menu Item', 'myFunction')
       .addSeparator()
       .addSubMenu(DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('My Submenu')
           .addItem('One Submenu Item', 'mySecondFunction')
           .addItem('Another Submenu Item', 'myThirdFunction'))
       .addToUi();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have a Document as a container for a script and therefore not possible to add a menu item to the Document.

There is an [open issue on the issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=721) which you can subscribe to.

Comment: I would like to be able to send selected content directly to Twitter. Do you have an idea to manage this ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1506051: This [article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/twitter_tutorial) will help you to start to work with Twitter from GAS.

Comment: This answer is obsolete.