# add custom menu to script-generated Google Document

Tags: google-apps-script

I know how to add a custom menu to a Google Document (when the script is 'inside' the Document -- see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357808/add-custom-menu-to-a-google-document)), but if I am creating a Document with a script

```
    var doc = DocumentApp.create('Doc name');
```

I can't figure out how to add a custom menu to that document at the same time. How do I get a reference to the Document?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is start from a 'template'. So have a template document which contains a script that adds the menu to the document. And in your script, make a copy of this template document and use it.
You can use the `DocsList` API to make copies of existing templates