# how to call a script from inside a google document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

In a google document, is there a way to make a piece of text (or a hyperlink or a button inside the text) calling a google app script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options are to create a custom menu or a sidebar panel. For further details see:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs

Related questions:

- [Is it possible to modify the Google Docs/Sheets right-click context menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27932041/1595451)
- [Add custom menu to a Google Document](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11357808/1595451)